# Does string formatting not work within an input() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, string-formatting

My code:

```
new_account = sys.argv[1]
confirm_new = input("Would you like to add {} to the dictionary?" +
                    "\ny or n\n".format(new_account))
```

This doesn't format the string to place the variable in place of {}. What's up?

Comment: Hint: What string is `.format` being called on?

Comment: Sure it does. It just is applied **before** your two separate strings are concatenated with `+`

Comment: If you remove the `+`, the two string literals are automatically concatenated (when compiling), and then your code works and is more efficient to boot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters was unaware I can do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `input`. It's just that addition has lower precedence than method calls:

```
>>> "{}" + "b".format('a')
'{}b'
```

Normally I just use automatic string concatenation if I have a multi-line string (just omit the `+`):

```
confirm_new = input("Would you like to add {} to the dictionary?"
                    "\ny or n\n".format(new_account))
```